# Selecting granule from ASTER Global DEM V2

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, aster

I am following this tutorial in order to download ASTER Global DEM V2 data:
http://www.echo.nasa.gov/reference/reverbastergdem_tutorial.htm
on http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/

Step 7 is to "Select the shopping cart button for the granules you desire to order."
Here there is an unordered list of 22'702 granules, such as ASTGTM2_N68W154.zip, ASTGTM2_N62E087.zip and so on...

I want to get the ASTGTM2_N41W002.zip (around Barcelona). However, I cannot search for this in this unordered list of 22'702 rows, the list being downloaded and shown bit by bit as I scroll down the list.

I tried the filter feature ("More search options"). But as soon as I add a filter option, whatever it is, such as the given example of "Equatorial Crossing Longitude: -45.0", then it reports "No granules found".

I tried also the map view, which I can zoom and center to Barcelona. But once there, there is not option to choose that granule.

Step 7 of the tutorial says "Select the shopping cart button for the granules you desire to order.".

How do I select the ASTGTM2_N41W002.zip granule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 4 of the tutorial it states "If desired, choose spatial and/or temporal search criteria". In essence, what you should do is draw a box on the map covering the area that you wish to search for data in (while leaving the temporal options alone).
This will give you only the tiles within your search box, rather than each and every tile available in the 'Select Granules' step.